# Android: How to make type converters (for Room) generic for all List of objects in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room as the local database solution in my project.
For every list of a certain object type I've added type converters to the project so the type convertor would look something like this:

```
@TypeConverter
fun convertListToString(video: List<VideoType>): String {

    val videoArray = arrayOfNulls<VideoType>(video.size)
    for (i in 0..video.size - 1) {
        videoArray[i] = video[i]
    }
    var str = ""
    val gson = Gson()
    for (i in videoArray.indices) {
        val jsonString = gson.toJson(videoArray[i])
        str = str + jsonString
        if (i < videoArray.size - 1) {
            str = str + strSeparator
        }
    }

    return str
}

@TypeConverter
fun convertStringToList(videoString: String): List<VideoType> {

    val videoArray = videoString.split(strSeparator.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
    val videos = ArrayList<VideoType>()
    val gson = Gson()
    for (i in 0 until videoArray.size - 1) {
        videos.add(gson.fromJson(videoArray[i], VideoType::class.java))
    }

    return videos
}
```

Problem only is that I have a whole bunch of List of different types that need to be converted, so currently I am just copying this code for every type. I would like to use generics, but so far haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

For example using something like:

```
@TypeConverter
inline fun <reified T> convertStringToList(string: String): List<T> {
    val objectArray = string.split(strSeparator.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
    val objects = ArrayList<T>()
    val gson = Gson()
    for (i in 0 until objectArray.size - 1) {
        objects.add(gson.fromJson(objectArray[i], T::class.java))
    }
    return objects
}
```

isn't working and causes compilation error with Android Studio giving me an error telling: **Type converters must be public**

Anyone an idea how I can use generics for my Room TypeConverter?

Comment: curious if you were able to solve this issue. If so, do you mind answering your question for others?

Comment: @fawaad Hi.. No i haven't been able to solve it in a generic way. I am also still curious if anyone has found a way to do it...

Comment: I am also having same problem, If you solve it then please post your solution

Comment: @SaurabhKhare Haven't found a generic solution yet. So far needed to add type converter for every list :(

Comment: Hi if that not a bother can you share related code in a GitHub repository I would like to run and test it. @RikvanVelzen

Answer (score 6):

Will something like this won't work for templating?

```
abstract class Converters<T> {

    @TypeConverter
    fun mapListToString(value: List<T>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(value, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun mapStringToList(value: String): List<T> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(value, type)
    }
}

// create 
class UserConverter : Converters<User>()

// usage
@TypeConverters(UserConverter::class)
abstract class TestDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

or from the current example what if I do

```kotlin
@TypeConverter
fun <T> mapStringToList(inputString: String): List<T> {
    val array = inputString
        .split(strSeparator.toRegex())
        .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
        .toTypedArray()
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()
    val gson = Gson()
    //  ----
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
    // ----
    return array.fold(result) { acc, item ->
        acc.add(gson.fromJson(item, type))
        acc
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with using Gson is performance, Gson uses reflection library which basically is too expensive. if you are just dealing with a few registries and small clases it will work Ok,however, as your data grows your performance will be hit drastically. I made that mistake a while ago and it's common sense, repeating the serialization/deserialization many times for complex classes and high volumes of data will trigger hikes in memory usage, and underperform.

Comment: This answer doeos not work correctly due to type erasure; you are actually creating `TypeToken<List<Any>>`, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572694).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Partially solution just for converting listToString

```
@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
fun listToString(list: List<*>?): String? = list.let {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

    gson.toJson(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a marker interface to convert classes to marker and vice versa but it didn't worked. I tried the `Object` class which most of Java extends, but it didn't work. I think the answer is that you can't use Generic in room typeconvertors.

Answer (score -1):

Well, basically the main idea of type converters is that databases can't read objects as a parameters.So you've to 2 ways first one is to do it manually with join relation inside the db, Or you can use type converter.
How type converter works?
It's simple it just convert your object to JSON String and save it as string.
In your problem, you've to add annotation before entity

```
private class YourDTO(
        @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
         Date date
```

And in DateConverter class

```
@TypeConverter
public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
    return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just tested this out, seems to do the base for what you'd be looking for. Up to you to tweak the function to your needs, but that should get you going :
Reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions

```
fun test() {
        val list1 = listOf("1", "2")
        val list2 = listOf(1, 2, 3)

        list1.convertToString()
        list2.convertToString()
    }

    fun List<Any>.convertToString(): String {
        var result = ""
        val gson = Gson()
        for (i in 0.. size - 1) {
            result += gson.toJson(get(i), get(i).javaClass)
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: This might do the trick of converting a list of any type into a string, but it not solving the issue for the use of typeConvertors with Room. If I use an extension on a List i want to convert to string (even with annotating it with @typeConverter) Room; "Cannot figure out how to save this field into database."