# Room generic TypeConverter

Tags: android, generics, gson, android-room, typeconverter

If someone can, please explain why this TypeConverter works:

```kotlin
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

abstract class SetConverter <T>{
    private val gson = Gson()
    private val setType = object: TypeToken<Set<T>>(){}.type

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(set: Set<T>): String{
        return gson.toJson(set, setType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJson(json: String): Set<T>{
        return gson.fromJson(json, setType)
    }
}
```

In Entity I use SetConverter through this implementation:

```kotlin
class CalendarSetConverter: SetConverter<Calendar>()
```

And this works.

But a similar TypeConverter for the class does not work.

```kotlin
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

abstract class ClassConverter<T> {
    private val gson = Gson()
    private val type = object : TypeToken<T>(){}.type

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(value: T): String{
        return gson.toJson(value, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    open fun fromJson(json: String): T{
        return gson.fromJson(json, type)
    }
}
```

Implementation in Entity:

```kotlin
class CalendarConverter : ClassConverter<Calendar>()
```

And this implementation throw error in runtime while read Calendar from database:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.Calendar`

How to create universal generic TypeConverter for Room?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your `CalendarSetConverter` is most likely also not behaving as you intended, but due to [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure) you most likely have not noticed the issue yet. If you try to use the elements inside the `Set` returned by `CalendarSetConverter` you will also run into a `ClassCastException`:

```kotlin
val set = CalendarSetConverter().fromJson(json);
// ClassCastException: LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class Calendar
val calendar: Calendar = set.first()
```

The underlying issue for both of this is also type erasure. You should never create an `object : TypeToken<...>` which captures a type parameter (e.g. `T`) unless that type parameter is [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Otherwise at compile time the upper bound of the type parameter is used, or `Any` if no explicit bound is specified.
So what your code actually looks like is this:

```kotlin
val setType = object : TypeToken<Set<Any>>(){}.type
```

```kotlin
val type = object : TypeToken<Any>(){}.type
```

And Gson deserializes `Any` (respectively `java.lang.Object`) as a `Map`, more precisely as its internal class `LinkedTreeMap`, which causes the `ClassCastException` you are experiencing. This does not apply to serialization (`toJson`) where Gson will use the runtime type when serializing `Any`.

To fix this you will have to take the `TypeToken` as constructor parameter, e.g.:

```kotlin
abstract class ClassConverter<T>(
    val typeToken: TypeToken<T>
) {
    private val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(value: T): String {
        return gson.toJson(value, typeToken.type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJson(json: String): T {
        // Note: This uses the fromJson(String, TypeToken) overload added in Gson 2.10
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeToken)
    }
}
```

And then create the converter subclasses like this:

```kotlin
class CalendarConverter : ClassConverter<Calendar>(TypeToken.get(Calendar::class.java))
class CalendarSetConverter : ClassConverter<Set<Calendar>>(object : TypeToken<Set<Calendar>>() {})
```

I don't know however if / how well this works with Room. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585075) provides better solutions to this.

Comment: Hi! The answer is excellent, thank you very much! But my converter for Set<Calendar> works, data is written to the database and read from there. Your converter for Set throws when compiling 'error: incompatible types: Set<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Set<Calendar>`.  Your ClassConverter is just great thank you again!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @Falchio, do you get this compilation error already only when including the code shown above, or do you get this error when referencing the code above in some way in your application? I am not seeing this compilation error at the moment, maybe it depends on the Kotlin version being used?

Comment: @Marcono1234, I found my mistake. I used `MutableSet<Calendar>` in `Entity`, but I used `Set<Calendar>` when extending `CalendarSetConverter`. As soon as I replaced `Set` with `MutableSet`, the project was built without errors.